# git CMD finds .gitconfig but Windows cmd does not?

Tags: windows, git, config

When I run git config under git cmd, all is well.  however when I run in in plain old Windows cmd, it can't find .gitconfig.  I can't changes the env vars Home, Homedrive or Homepath since those are set by our corporate ad team.

I'd like to know why git cmd works but git from windows cmd doesn't and what i can do about it. See screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot showing env vars in both shells:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your home folder in the git bash is a different folders than %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% in the Windows cmd prompt. Echo the two paths and compare them.

Comment: yeah they are the same. I updated the original post

Comment: Interesting, The git-cmd has HOME env var set as the concatenation of HOMEDIR and HOMEPATH.  When I set that, all was well.   OTOH, git is complaining about the wrong thing, which is misleading.  OTOOH, it should probably point at %USERPROFILE% since that is local, and my other location is network, which would of course fail if I was on the road.

Comment: Did you solve this? I assume I have the same problem, git-bash works fine and changing the HOME in the Git/etc/profile works, but it does not affect the git-cmd. I am trying to use GIt in my Powershell and Powershell I assume uses git-cmd.