# git config command returns: fatal: unable to read config file '%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.gitconfig': No such file or directory

Tags: git, config, global

On My Windows 10 box, when I run:

```
git config --global -l
```

it fails with the message:

> fatal: unable to read config file '%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.gitconfig':
>   No such file or directory

Both env vars look ok (to me) and .gitgconfig is where it should be I think:

```
C:\Users\BRITTG2>echo %homedrive%
P:

C:\Users\BRITTG2>echo %homepath%
\

C:\Users\BRITTG2>dir %homedrive%%homepath%.gitconfig
 Volume in drive P is home
 Volume Serial Number is 8076-09DA

 Directory of P:\

03/25/2019  02:34 PM               658 .gitconfig
               1 File(s)            658 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  2,908,136,849,408 bytes free
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

Run powershell as administrator (but you can use cmd, Git bash, etc) and try again.
In my case:

```
cd C:\ROstuff\ROprojects\Python\
git init
git config --global user.name "Rodrigo H Padilla"
git config --global user.email "Myemail@email.com"
git config --global -l
```

Comment: Might it not be better to change permissions instead of always running as admin?

Comment: My workstation is locked down and I cannot  run as admin

Answer (score 3):

Found an old post (mine!) with a workaround:

[git CMD finds .gitconfig but Windows cmd does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339943/git-cmd-finds-gitconfig-but-windows-cmd-does-not)

Bottom line: git on windows is not using homedrive and homepath.  It is using the env var home.  When I set that, it works