# What's the proper way to set git email and name in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-for-windows

I'm getting the following error in Visual Studio Code on Windows when I try to commit code:

```
2022-12-19 07:17:00.902 [info] Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: no email was given and auto-detection is disabled
```

So I run this command:

```
PS E:\path\to\repo> git config --global user.email "john.doh@domainname.com"
error: could not lock config file %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

I tried the same from Git-Bash with the same result:

```
johndoh@myhost MINGW64 /
$ git config --global user.email "john.doh@domainname.com"
error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

I installed git via the Visual Studio Installer:

```
C:\Users\johndoh>which git
C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe

C:\Users\johndoh>git --version
git version 2.38.1.windows.1
```

How do am I supposed to set this up for git on Windows with Visual Studio code? It seems like [others may have run into this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21352) but it went away for them after they logged out and then back in again. Some of the other related Stack Overflow questions are:

1. [git CMD finds .gitconfig but Windows cmd does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339943/git-cmd-finds-gitconfig-but-windows-cmd-does-not)
2. [git config command returns: fatal: unable to read config file '%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.gitconfig': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797060/git-config-command-returns-fatal-unable-to-read-config-file-homedrivehomep)

Comment: Environment variables `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH%` are not expanded. Try to run `git config --global ...` in Git Bash.

Comment: I tried the same from Bit Bash and got a similar result (I added this to my question).